# Use an output from a previous deployment in Google Cloud Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, infrastructure

I'm fairly new to GDM but I've a few years of CloudFormation under my belt. I'm trying to split the deployment of my resources into multiple `deployments`. I'm now running into an issue where I need to reference the outputs from a deployment which is already live into a fresh new deployment. One example:

- I deploy networking-specific resources in a dedicated `network` deployment, which is in charge of creating a `dns.v1.managedZone` DNS zone
- I now want to deploy a CloudSQL instance with another deployment, in which I'd like to create a `gcp-types/dns-v1:resourceRecordSets` DNS records set for which the `managedZone` property should reference the zone created by the other deployment

is it at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References can only be used on the [same deployment](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/using-references)

Meaning, that you will need to combine your network deployment and CloudSQL deployment together.

You can do so by making your [deployments into templates](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/using-multiple-templates).

Please be advised that such questions should be directed to stackoverflow in the future.